# Relative files in Django

Tags: django

In my django project, i got the following `urls.py`'s `urlpattern`:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name="index")
```

in `views.py`'s `index()` function, I got:

```
template = loader.get_template('stats/index.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {...})
return HTTPResponse(template.render(context))
```

Now, the `index.html` file looks great. The problem is that relative paths (including subdirectories) in the html code won't show, even though they exist in the same folder as `index.html`.

What can I do?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood your question right, but there is a difference between the loaded template and static files (like pictures and other (media) files). These should not be served via django, but via your webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think for a second about what relative paths *mean*.

Let's take the case that I have a local html file, `/users/me/mysite/index.html`. That file looks like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="foo.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The browser is what's fetching the image. It doesn't know anything at all about the file structure on disk. That src= doesn't say "look in the same directory as index.html," it says "look at the same parent URL as index.html," or `/users/me/mysite/foo.jpg`. The distinction is that this is a URL, not a path (though it looks like one).

So how does Django work? Django doesn't serve files. your URL could be totally different from `/index.html` - and in fact it is! It's just site root, in your case.

So let's say you do simply use the relative path `src="foo.jpg"` - you're asking the server for localhost/foo.jpg. But you don't have a URL describing what foo.jpg is. Django doesn't even know where to look!

Luckily, they've though of this. [Here is the link to the docs for the static files app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/), which describes the system in detail. The gist is you've got some settings in settings.py to play with: `STATIC_ROOT`, `STATIC_URL`, and `STATICFILES_DIRS` to play with. `STATIC_URL` means 'at which URL root will I find static files referenced by the static tag in templates?'. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is the list of local directories that you store static files like CSS and JS in. You can store images here too, but use discretion - sometimes you want images served from your application server, sometimes you want a separate media server, and sometimes you want a whole CDN behind the heavy load of images you serve (there are `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` options for this, to separate normal code (css, js) from media (images, videos)).

So let's have an example. In my base.djhtml template I have

```
<head>
    ...
    <link href="{% static "/static/ui/css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
</head>
```

in my settings.py I have

```
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..', 'MyApp/static'),
    #'/Users/me/Development/Python/MyProj/MyApp/static',
)
```

and of course in `/Users/me/Development/Python/MyProj/MyApp/static` is `ui/css/base.css` and plenty of other goodies like javascript

In settings I've also got

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..', 'static_files')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

which is to say when I run 'manage.py collectstatic' all my static files, from all apps, get shuffled into static_files at my project root - in deployment, I have nginx pointed at that directory specifically to serve static files based on requests to /static/. You seem not to be at deployment yet, so don't worry about that or collectstatic - the dev server takes care of it for you.

now, when I run the server, the link gets rendered as

```
<link href="/static/ui/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and `http://localhost:8000/static/ui/css/base.css` is automatically served by the development server! In production, the /static/ url is served by nginx rather than getting forwarded to the apps server.